# Power Supply Adapter compatability

Tags: power-supply, amperage

Apologies if this has been previously asked and answred, I did search but found nothing that provided the answer:

I have an HP Envy8, that came with a power adapter rated Output: 19.5V 3.33A. I also have a loan of an HP Envy x360, for which I don't have a power adapter to hand, but know the rating is 19.5V 2.31A.

My question is: Can I use the higher Amp rated adaptor (3.33A) with the lower rated machine (2.31A) without possible damage.  (I have checked and the adapters fit).

Comment: I apologize for the duplication in that respect. I really did look as I am aware of wasting peoples time answering already-asked questions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in using this adapter since the output voltage is the same.
It is the load, in this case the laptop, that determines the max. current taken.
You can use it safely.